# What the range of $r$ and $\theta$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

If $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan \frac{y}{x}$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$, what the range of $r$ and $\theta$?

I think since $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$ then $0\leq r\leq 1$.

since $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$, then $\frac{y}{x}>0$ so $0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Does this answer correct? (Or maybe $r$ depend on $\theta$?)

Comment: you are not correct fully

Comment: If $x=y=1$ what is $r$?

Comment: If $x=y=1$ then $r=\sqrt{2}$. So my answer is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture. You will  see that $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac 1 {\cos \theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac {\pi}4$ and  $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac 1 {\sin \theta}$ for $\frac {\pi} 4 \leq \theta \leq \frac {\pi} 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the problem involves Arctan$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, $x=0$ is outlawed.

Therefore, $0 < x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1.$  Therefore,

- $~r^2 \in (0,2] \implies r \in (0,\sqrt{2}]$.
- $\frac{y}{x} \in [0, +\infty) \implies \theta \in [0, \pi/2).$

---

**Edit**
If you allow the interpretation that $x$ may equal $0$, then **superficially**, the changes are that $r$ may equal $0$, and that $\theta$ may equal $\pi/2$.

The problem with this superficial interpetation is that when $r = 0$, the concept of $\theta$ is **meaningless**.  Therefore, it could be argued that even when $x=0$ is permitted, $r$ is **still** not permitted to equal $0$,

Comment: It does not involve $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$, but the $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$, which is well-defined for $x=0$ as well.

Comment: @Botond I just read about [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and I therefore disagree with your comment.  In my opinion, atan2$(y,x)$ is a misinterpretation of the query's explicit: $\theta=\arctan \frac{y}{x}$.  As such, absent some clear indication of the intent of the problem composer in favor of atan2$(y,x)$ I disagree with your comment.